# ¿Cómo puedo sumar las columna en una tabla dinamica?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Alguien que me pueda ayudar con este problema, esta eternamente agradecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="caja6">
  <div class="alcance">
    <h1>DETALLE MATERIALES, REPUESTO E INSUMOS</h1> [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]
  </div>
  <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">

    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
       <div class='btn btn-success' id="btnNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">Nueva</div>
     </label>
     <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id="tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo">
      <tr>
        <th>Detalles De Insumos</th>
        <th>Unidad</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Precio Unitario</th>
        <th>Valor Total ($)</th>
        <th>OPCION</th>
      </tr>
      <?php for($i=0; $i<sizeof($tabla2); ++$i) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="detalle_insumo[]" value="" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="unidad_insumo[]" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cantidad_insumo[]" id="cantidad_insumo[]" onChange="suma();" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="precio_unitario_insumo[]" id="precio_unitario_insumo[]" onChange="suma();" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_total_insumo[]" id="valor_total_insumo[]" value="" ></td>
        <td class="text-center">

         <div class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</div>

       </td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
   </table>                 
 </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function funcNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo() 
{
  $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo")
  .append
  (
    $('<tr>')
    .append
    (
      $('<td>')
      .append
      (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_insumo[]')
        )
      )
    .append
    (
      $('<td>')
      .append
      (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'unidad_insumo[]')
        )
      )
    .append
    (
      $('<td>')
      .append
      (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_insumo[]').attr('onChange', 'suma();')
        )
      )
    .append
    (
     $('<td>')
     .append
     (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'precio_unitario_insumo[]').attr('onChange', 'suma();')
      )
     )
    .append
    (
     $('<td>')
     .append
     (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_insumo[]').attr('readonly')
      )
     )
    .append
    (
      $('<td>').addClass('text-center')

      .append
      (
        $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
        )            
      )        
    );
}
```

Comment: Primero tienes que agregar el html y como generas las columnas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Listo @Einer hay agregue el codigo

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que te sucede que problema da tu código y que esperabas obtener?

Comment: @Monsiens te lo ponía en otra pregunta, lee [ask] y completa el [tour]. En lugar de crear preguntas duplicadas, edita la pregunta original. El sitio no funciona a base de publicar la misma mala pregunta una y otra vez hasta que alguien la conteste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elimina la asignación del evento onChange de los dos campos, dejando tu función de esta manera

```
    var sumaValores = function(){
    //Obtengo la última fila ingresada en la tabla
    var fila = $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo").find('tr:last');
    //Obtengo el campo referente a la cantidad de insumo ':eq(2)'
    var campo1 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)'); 
    //Obtengo el campo referente al precio_unitario_insumo ':eq(3)'
    var campo2 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(3)');
    //Obtengo el campo donde se escribirá el resultado
    var destino = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');

    campo1.on('change', function(){
        destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())+parseInt(campo2.val()));
    });

    campo2.on('change', function(){
        destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())+parseInt(campo2.val()));
    }); 
};

function funcNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo() 
{
  $("#tablaDetalleMaterialEinsumo")
  .append
  (
    $('<tr>')
    .append
    (
      $('<td>')
      .append
      (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_insumo[]')
        )
      )
    .append
    (
      $('<td>')
      .append
      (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'unidad_insumo[]')
        )
      )
    .append
    (
      $('<td>')
      .append
      (
        $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_insumo[]')
        )
      )
    .append
    (
     $('<td>')
     .append
     (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'precio_unitario_insumo[]')
      )
     )
    .append
    (
     $('<td>')
     .append
     (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_insumo[]').attr('readonly')
      )
     )
    .append
    (
      $('<td>').addClass('text-center')

      .append
      (
        $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
        )            
      )        
    );

    sumaValores();
}
```

Agregué la función **sumaValores** que se encargará de vincular el evento **onChange** de los dos campos de la nueva fila creada con la respectiva suma de sus valores.

Comment: no te entendi lo utlimo @Dariel RAmos Diaz

Comment: no me funciona Dariel :(

Comment: a hora si funciono pero el primero no me lo tomó eso si

Comment: o sea desde la segunda columna me empieza a contar bien, y te agradezco por la ayuda que me has brindado @Dariel Ramos

Comment: Ramos es normal que al momento de ingresar el valor me de una alerta de [object Object]

Comment: No es normal al no ser que tengas algún alert en el código algo que no creo haber dejado suelto ;) si deseas que funcione en la primera fila tambien solo debes llamar a la función **sumaValores()** despues de su implementación o detras de la implementación de **function funcNuevaDetalleMaterialEinsumo()**. Saludos

Comment: A hora funciona todo bien, mil gracia por tu ayuda a hora estoy haciendo que sume el valor total de la fila valor total.  @Dariel Ramos Diaz

Comment: OKOK no hay de que para eso estamos. ;P

Comment: Ramos Diaz, otra pregunta, si quisiera sumar el total, tengo que ocupar la misma funcion?. Saludos

Comment: subi una imagen @Dariel Ramos estaré eternamente agradecido si me ayuda con eso saludos

Comment: Cuáles valores sumarias en esa operación y donde lo mostrarias?

Comment: Sumaria la fila de valor total, y este es el codigo igual subi una imagen mas arriba no se si lo viste. y este es el codigo donde debe ir la el total

Comment: <div class="unitario">
  <h2>Costos de insumos</h2><input type="text" name="Valor_unitario" id="valor_unitario" class="form-input" placeholder="Valor Unitario"> 
</div>

Comment: Has lo siguiente publica tu pregunta nueva que ya se como hacerlo pero no esta bien ponerlo en los comentarios. Te dare una pista solo tienes que recorrer los campos donde está el total en cada fila en la función **sumaValores** e ir sumandolo y al final poner ese valor en el campo que deseas.

Comment: Cuando la publiques ponme un comentario aqui para saberlo

Comment: Ramos Diaz, ya lo publique, saludos